# Hive Incremental import data - New Columns

Tags: hive, sqoop

How to import a table into `Hive` from `sql server` using **`Sqoop`** and handle if any **new**columns are added and how to load new columns data into `hive` without data loss?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to import data directly to hive :

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://11.11.111.11;databaseName=dswFICO" \ --username sqoop\ --password sqoop \ --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \ --table KNA1 \ --split-by rowkey --hive-import -m 1
```

If you don't want to loss the source data copy while loading then the best way would be to create external table over that existing hdfs directory OR you can also make a copy of your source directory and create an external hive table that should point to new dir location.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply and I have completed this. I can able to import the data from SQL to Hive using Sqoop successfully. My question is :  For Instance, Initially a SQL table 5 columns with 5 columns data in it and I can able to import the data using sqoop.     Now SQL Table is altered with 8 Columns ( 3 New Columns), Now how I will import the new columns into the existing table in hive. I need to load the new column data (3 COLUMNS DATA) without any data loss in hive table. What are the methods available to load the data.

Comment: Sqoop is not supporting HIVE external tables at the moment.Any imports using scoop creates a managed table, in real world scenario it is very important to have EXTERNAL tables. As of now we have to execute ALTER statement to change table properties to make the table as external table which is not a big deal but it would nice have an option in scoop to specify type of table which is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the external table from sqoop import, where you will basically get the data into a file in hdfs and you will have to built a external table on top of the table.

Simple sqoop import example, which will get the data to hdfs but nothing related to hive.

```
$ sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb \
--username root \
--table emp_add \
--m 1 \
--target-dir /queryresult
```

After you have data in the /queryresult path, just built an external table on top of that location.